# NodeJS Express Mongoose return empty []

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

I tried to make a MEAN stack app, but my API fails to give my requested data.

server.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyparser = require("body-parser");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const port = process.env.PORT; 
const dburi = process.env.DB_URI; 

//Routes
const volcanoesRoute = require('./api/routes/volcano.routes');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(
  dburi,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  },
).then(
  () => {
    console.log('Connected to mongoDB');
  },
  (err) => console.log('Error connecting to mongoDB', err),
  { useNewUrlParser: true }
);


//Express app
const app = express();

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use('/api/vulcanoes', volcanoesRoute);
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`running at port ${port}`);
});
```

Routes file:

```
const express = require('express');
const volcanoController = require('../controllers/volcanoController');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/getallvulcanoes', volcanoController.getAllVolcanoes);

module.exports = router;
```

Controller file:

```
const VolcanoSchema = require('../models/volcano.models');

const getAllVulcanoes = (req, res) => {
    VolcanoSchema.find((err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({message: err});
      } else {
        res.status(200).json(results);
      }
    });
  };

  module.exports = {getAllVolcanoes};
```

Model file

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const VolcanoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Volcano_name:{
        type: String,
    },
    Country:{
        type: String,
    },
    Type:{
        type: String,
    },
    Latitude:{
        type: Number,
    },
    Longtitude:{
        type: Number,
    },
    Elevation:{
        type: Number,
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Volcano', VolcanoSchema);
```

The thing is that i have a working example but most of the code is decrepitated... but it the respond is always giving me this

[image: request example]

It would be nice if someone point out what i am doing wrong

EDIT: I switched to postgresql for my database hopefully this will work

Comment: [example of my document](https://imgur.com/a/sPvjEQd)

Comment: i am sure my app is connected correctly to my db, my clusters metrics also indicate my read actions so i guess that it is connected the right way

Comment: Amazed! same code works for me ..

Comment: wow what ? can you publish your code please ?

Comment: sure, Here is  the link of `Github` https://github.com/kedarSedai/code-of-Clumpsypenguin

Comment: ok I cloned your repo and only did npm install and changed the database url, but I still get an empty request ...

Comment: I tried to explain in `Readme` file in `Github `check once.

Comment: The only difference here is that i store my dburl in a .env file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214952/discussion-between-kedar-sedai-and-clumpsypenguin).

Answer (score 0):

You should fix the Controller (`VulcanoSchema.find` needs an empty object as parameter):

**Controller file:**

```js
const VulcanoSchema = require('../models/vulcano.models');

const getAllVulcanoes = (req, res) => {
  VulcanoSchema.find({}, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({message: err});
    } else {
      res.status(200).json(results);
    }
  });
};

module.exports = {getAllVulcanoes};
```

Comment: The first param should be Object/ObjectId. The second, a callback function.

Comment: You're right i thought so too but i just tried it and his method seems to work fine so i don't think that's his problem

Comment: There's an overload for find(callback?: (err: any, res: T[]) => void)

Comment: hi i added that empty object in front of (err,results) but that does not seems the fix the issue